# Replace text in string with exceptions

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace some text in a java string, but I don't want to replace it if the text is inside a section defined by $ and &.
Example: The string "$foo& bar foo" with replace text foo would be "$foo& bar $foo&".
So the replace text must be escaped using $ and & but not if the escape is already applied. Currently I'm using the regular expression `([^\\$]|^)text([^&]|$)` and it works quite well but if only one of the symbols is found the regex doesn't match.
Example: for the text "bar $foo" the regular expression `([^\\$]|^)foo([^&]|$)` doesn't matches but I want a not match only if **both** sign are found.

Comment: Will there be multiple words between $ and &?

Comment: @TheLostMind no, only one

Comment: add some small, complete and runnable example of what you're doing and we can try to help

Comment: @greywolf82 - So basically, all `foo`'s should be replaced by `$foo&` provided the string is not already `$foo&` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use *negative lookbehind* for `$` and *negative lookahead* for `&`. This will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "$foo& bar foo";
    s= s.replaceAll("(?<!\\$)foo(?!&)", "\\$foo&");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

O/P :

```
$foo& bar $foo&
```